# Is the plural of 'a friend's book' 'a friend's books' or 'friend's books'?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles, syntactic-analysis

this question concerns only the **INDEFINITE** article, I don't care for the definite article or 'of' forms here.

In the following construction

```
a friend's book
a boy's toy
a guy's car
```

Question: do you still write the indefinite article if the noun following the possessive noun is plural?

```
a friend's book >> a friend's books / ø friend's books?
a boy's toy >> a boy's toys / ø boy's toys?
a guy's car >> a guy's cars / ø guy's cars?
```

If the 'a/an' article is removed, why?

Thanks.

P.S if anyone could cite a link to this particular topic, that would be be great.

Comment: Not going to post as an answer because I don't have a link to a source that backs me up, but as far as I'm aware pluralising the noun following the possessive pronoun has no effect on whether an article should be used, so you would keep it in. Consider the example sentence "I'm holding onto a friend's books for him."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*, on page 148, that the indefinite article is part of Group A determiners:

> Group A determiners
>
> These help to identify things — to say whether they are known or unknown to the hearer, which one(s) the speaker is talking about, whether the speaker is thinking of particular examples or speaking in general, etc.
>
> **articles**: *a/an*, *the*
>
> **possessives**: *my*, *your*, *his*, *her*, *its*, *our*, *your*, *their*, *one's*, *whose*
>
> **demonstratives**: *this*, *these*, *that*, *those*
>
> We cannot put two Group A determiners together. We can say ***the** house*, ***my** house* or ***this** house*, but not ***the my** house*, ***this my** house* or ***my this** house*. In order to put together the meanings of possessive and article/demonstrative, we have to use the structure ***a/this … of mine/yours*** etc.
>
> Nouns with possessive *'s* can be used like determiners (e.g. ***Britain's** weather*).

So, in your example, you have to determine whether *a* introduces the noun in the possessive determiner, *friend*, or the noun introduced by that possessive determiner, *book*.

***A** book **of me*** * is not ***a my** book* * but ***my** book*. Similarly, ***a** book **of a friend*** * is not ***a a friend's** book* * but ***a friend's** book*, where the first indefinite article, the one introducing *book*, has disappeared.

In the plural, *books **of a friend*** * is not ***friend's** books* * but ***a friend's** books*. The singular indefinite article cannot be left out since it introduces *friend*, still in the singular, in the possessive determiner.

*Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan, Oxford University Press, Second Edition, 1995

Interestingly, as the article introducing the noun disappears before a possessive determiner, it would not possible to distinguish between

***John's** friend*, meaning ***the** friend **of John*** *

and

***John's** friend* * meaning ***a** friend **of John*** *.

That is why, in order to raise the ambiguity ***John's** friend* might cause (was the removed article definite or indefinite?), another structure exists, which is only used when the removed article is indefinite:

***a** friend **of John's***.

Comment: I give you the edge over other quality answers because you've cited a source. Thanks

Comment: @Sam: thanks. As a foreigner, I find Michael Swan's 'Practical English Usage' a very useful, to-the-point, no-frills, easy-to-use handbook

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the possessive noun or pronoun remains singular.

As you point out, in the cited examples, the indefinite article is associated with the possessive noun or pronoun, not the noun they modify. As such, when you pluralize the main noun (sometimes called *head noun*), the possessive noun or pronoun remains single, and the singular indefinite pronoun continues to be correct.

However if you were to pluralize the possessive pronoun, this would not be the case.

> my friends' books
>
> boys' toys
>
> some guys' cars

These cannot take a singular indefinite article since the possessive is plural.

In fact you could even have a plural possessive and a singular main noun. For example, if a house were occupied by several friends, you could say

> some friends' house

but not

> a friends' house

The latter would be confusing since the singular indefinite article jars with the plural possessive noun, *friends'*.

However, there are cases where a singular indefinite article *can* be used with a plural possessive noun followed by a singular main noun.

> a girls' bathroom
>
> a farmers' market

In these cases, the possessive nouns are more closely associated with following noun, forming a noun phrase that has a recognized sense as a unit. The singular indefinite article is associated with the main noun, not the possessive modifier.

Whether the use of a singular indefinite article/plural possessive noun/singular main noun creates ambiguity probably depends on the familiarity of the noun phrase.

(Thanks to @PeterShor for this last point.)

Comment: I don't think "farmers market" is a possessive construction.  It's a noun compound. Note that "farmers" has more stress than "market", which is typical for a compound but not a possessive.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

If the genitive is a Modifier within a larger noun phrase, then it will have no effect on whether we use an article or not. This will just depend on whether the head noun in the larger noun phrase is plural. Modifiers in noun phrases do not have their own Determiners.

However, if the genitive noun phrase has the function of Determiner within the larger phrase, then it may need its own article. This will depend on whether the head noun in the genitive NP is singular. If it is it will require a mandatory Determiner of its own (possibly an article such as ***a***).

---

**Full answer**

1. [a] [dogs' home].
2. [dogs' homes]
3. [a dog]'s [home]
4. [a dog]'s [homes]
5. [the dogs]' [home]
6. [dogs]' [homes]

Just like clauses have two main parts, a Subject and a Predicate, noun phrases have two parts too. They are made up of a Determiner and a Head. In ***a pen*** the word ***a*** is the Determiner, and ***pen*** is the Head. If we add an adjective to the noun phrase it will go inside the Head where it modifies the head noun. So in ***an expensive pen***,  ***an*** is the Determiner and ***expensive pen*** is the Head.

**Examples 1 & 2**

In example (1) above we see the simple noun phrase "a dogs' home". It might help if we give an example sentence:

- My friend couldn't look after my dog this holidays, so I had to put her in a dogs' home.

In this noun phrase the Determiner is ***a*** and the Head is ***dogs' home***. Inside the Head we can see ***home*** being modified by the word ***dogs'***. Often we see adjectives doing the job of modifying the head noun, but we can also see nouns doing it too, for example: *a **gas** cooker*. In this instance we can see a genitively inflected noun (technically a nominal) ***dogs'***  doing this job. Here the word ***dogs'*** isn't telling you the owner of the home, it is telling you what type of home it is. Notice that because the head noun, **home** is singular, the noun phrase must have a Determiner, in this case the word ***a***.

Example (2) is the plural form of (1) where there is more than one home being considered. It is because the head noun *homes* is plural that this is a plural noun phrase. Because ***homes*** is plural we don't need a Determiner at all. Here's an example sentence:

- This holidays I kenneled my two dogs at different dogs' homes.

So this noun phrase has a Head, but no Determiner.

**Examples 3 & 4**

Example (3) doesn't tell us what type of home we are talking about, but it tells us the *owner* of the home. Here's an example sentence:

- A dog's home is its castle.

In this large noun phrase the Head is ***home***. The Determiner is not the word ***a*** but the smaller noun phrase ***a dog's***, which consists of the noun phrase ***a dog*** along with the genitive particle/clitic/inflection ***'s***. Notice that inside this smaller noun phrase the head noun *dog* is singular and so this smaller noun phrase requires its own Determiner, the word *a*.

The plural version of this noun phrase is example (4). Here we have more than one home:

- A dog's homes are its kennel and its master's living room.

But we still only have one dog. The Determiner here is the singular noun phrase ***a dog's***. Because there is only one dog, we still need the Determiner inside this smaller noun phrase, the word ***a***. Of course we don't need a Determiner for the larger noun phrase because the word ***homes*** is plural. We can easily have sentences like:

- Homes are very important to dogs.

But if we want to show whose homes we are talking about then the Determiner is important here for showing the possessor.

**Examples 5 & 6**

In (5) we have the Determiner ***the dogs'***, where the plural noun *dogs'* indicates that this single home is owned by two or more dogs together:

- The dogs' home is an old shed in an abandoned field. They like it very much though.

Here the head noun ***home*** is singular and so we must have a Determiner when this word is used with this meaning. Again as with example (4) when ***homes*** is plural we do not need a Determiner, but if we want to show the possessor of the homes in question then we will need to use a genitive noun phrase as a Determiner:

- Dogs' homes should be kept warm in the winter.

Notice that because the noun phrase in the Determiner is plural, it doesn't need a Determiner of its own. However, if we want to show the possessor we will need to use a genitive noun phrase as a Determiner. The head noun in the noun phrase inside the Determiner, ***dogs***, is plural. For this reason, it does not require its own Determiner.

**Conclusion**

If the genitive is a modifier within a larger noun phrase, then it will have no effect on whether we use an article or not. This will just depend on whether the head noun in the noun phrase is plural. Modifiers in noun phrases do not have their own Determiners.

However, if the genitive noun phrase has the function of Determiner in a larger phrase, then it may need its own article. This will depend on whether the noun in the genitive is singular or not. If it is plural it will not need a Determiner of its own, if it is singular it will.

- A friend's book (article needed within Determiner because of singular *friend*)
- A friend's books (article needed within Determiner because of singular *friend*)
- People's need to be appreciated  (no article needed within Determiner because of plural *people*)
- People's needs (no article needed within Determiner because of plural *people*)
- A ladies' wristwatch (the Head is singular phrase *ladies wristwatch*, article required)
- Ladies wristwatches (the Head is plural phrase *ladies wristwatches*, no article required)

Comment: Some of your examples supposed to be possessive constructions are noun compounds (and shouldn't have apostrophes).  E.g., "a dogs' home" is really "a dogs-home", where "dogs-home" or "dogs home" is a compound noun meaning "home for/of dogs".  As is typical of compounds, main stress is on the first part.  Compare "a dog's home", which has main stress on "home".

Comment: @GregLee I  thought that too originally. However, it seems to be a much used example, and is one of the main ones used in CaGEL. As I'm not hot on compounds, modifiers and attributive complements of nouns, I thought I'd defer to their better judgement here ... I don't think the stress test is definitive, is it? When considering this I wondered whether *home* was maybe like *place* and *stuff* in that it avoids stress. (Compare "Come round to *my* place" and "Come round to my *place*", which is weird.

Comment: @GregLee What do you think of "Can I have a child's portion please" or "Can I have two child's portions please" - given that the plural of *child* is *children* and so therefore *child's* can only be interpreted as a genitive?

Comment: "a *childs* portion" has the stress and the interpretation of a compound, if it means "a portion suitable for a child".  I don't know what the "s" is doing there.  I don't understand some of your examples.  Nonetheless, the difference between "a dog's *home*" and "a *dogs* home" seems clear to me.

Comment: @GregLee We don't say "Can I have a child portion" do we?

Comment: "a *child* portion" sounds okay to me.